# Custom Windows Authentication Package not loaded

Tags: c++, custom-authentication, local-security-authority, windows-logon

I'm writing a custom windows authentication package, but the LSA does not load my Dll.

I have the following methods exported via the `.def` file

```
EXTERN_C __declspec(dllexport) NTSTATUS NTAPI SpLsaModeInitialize(
    ULONG LsaVersion,
    PULONG PackageVersion,
    PSECPKG_FUNCTION_TABLE * ppTables,
    PULONG pcTables
) {
    __LOG_TRACE_FUNC_BEGIN(); // Write a log entry to C:\temp\log.txt

    *PackageVersion = SECPKG_INTERFACE_VERSION;
    *ppTables = sp_lsa_function_table;
    *pcTables = 1;

    __LOG_TRACE_FUNC_END(); // Write a log entry to C:\temp\log.txt

    return 0;
}
```

I also have the `DllMain` and `DllInit` functions.

```
BOOL APIENTRY DllMain(HMODULE hModule,
                       DWORD  ul_reason_for_call,
                       LPVOID lpReserved)
{
    __LOG_TRACE_FUNC_BEGIN(); // Write a log entry to C:\temp\log.txt

    switch (ul_reason_for_call)
    {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
    case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
    case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
        break;
    }

    __LOG_TRACE_FUNC_END(); // Write a log entry to C:\temp\log.txt

    return TRUE;
}


BOOLEAN DllInit(IN PVOID DllHandle, IN ULONG Reason, IN PCONTEXT Context OPTIONAL)
{
    __LOG_TRACE_FUNC_BEGIN(); // Write a log entry to C:\temp\log.txt

    switch (Reason) 
    {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
#if defined (DEBUG)
        DebugBreak();
#endif
        InitializeCriticalSection(&DllCritSect);
        break;
    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
        EnterCriticalSection(&DllCritSect);
        LeaveCriticalSection(&DllCritSect);
        DeleteCriticalSection(&DllCritSect);
        break;
    }

    __LOG_TRACE_FUNC_END(); // Write a log entry to C:\temp\log.txt

    return TRUE;

    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(Context);
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(DllHandle);

}
```

I have the export definition in `dap.def` as below,

```
EXPORTS

DllMain
DllInit
SpLsaModeInitialize
```

I also have the `dap.dll.manifest` file (*even though I'm not sure if it is required. The manifest file was required for another part of the project, a credential provider*)

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='yes'?>
<assembly xmlns='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1' manifestVersion='1.0'>
    <dependency>
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity 
                type='win32' 
                name='Microsoft.VC80.DebugCRT' 
                version='8.0.50608.0' 
                processorArchitecture='x64' 
                publicKeyToken='1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b' />
        </dependentAssembly>
    </dependency>
</assembly>
```

My Dll is compiled for `Release/x64`.

I'm signing my Dll (dap.dll) as below (*not sure if this step is mandatory*)

```
makecert.exe -sv dap.pvk -n "CN=Dallas" dap.cer -r
pvk2pfx.exe -pvk dap.pvk -spc dap.cer -pfx dap.pfx -po 123
signtool.exe sign /f "dap.pfx" /p 123 "dap.dll"
```

Then I move my file, dap.dll, into `Windows\System32` in the target Windows 10 VM and add the following registry entry.
[image]

I've also tried adding the same into the `Security Packages`.

[image]

Then I restart the VM.

But none of these attempts worked, and my Dll never gets called (*I don't see any log entries created.*).

Here is my OS info,

[image]

My questions are,

1. Am I doing everything right? or am I missing any step?
2. Does the signing step mandatory, and Am I doing it right?
3. When the Local Security Authority process ignores my DLL, does it create any event entries? I tried enabling `%SystemRoot%\System32\Winevt\Logs\Microsoft-Windows-LSA%4Operational.evtx` events, but nothing useful came up. Is there any other place?
4. Are there any other way to troubleshoot this?

Cheers,

Comment: signing step is not mandatory.
you have to implement spInitialize(), spGetInfo() and spshutdown() and provide them in SpLsaModeInitialize function table

Comment: Were you able to make this work? I am unable to make my package load as well? Pretty much all the mandatory function return the NTSTATUS of STATUS_NOT_IMPLEMENTED. So It should not fail mid function as well...?

Each time that I am "RDPing" to the machine only {"AuthenticationPackageName":"C:\\Windows\\system32\\msv1_0.DLL : MICROSOFT_AUTHENTICATION_PACKAGE_V1_0"} is loaded...

Wonder if you were able to fix your issue?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you don't have to sign your package or use a manifest file.

And you are not implementing the [required methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthn/authentication-functions#functions-implemented-by-authentication-packages) for an authentication package.

My def file is as below

```
LIBRARY

EXPORTS
LsaApInitializePackage
LsaApLogonUserEx
LsaApLogonTerminated
LsaApCallPackage
LsaApCallPackagePassthrough
LsaApCallPackageUntrusted = LsaApCallPackage
```

As you can see I don't even have a DllMain or DllInit entry. And you don't need any Sp* methods either unless you also want to implement a security package.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced similar problem in hp windows 10 Pro where LSA Protection is enabled by default which prevented LSA from loading Custom AP dll. This can be verified in eventvwr (Applications and services\Microsoft\Windows\CodeIntegrity\Operational)

When LSA protection is enabled dll has to be signed as per Microsoft signing requirements.

As a temporary solution LSA protection can be disabled but it is not recommended.
[this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/security/credentials-protection-and-management/configuring-additional-lsa-protection) has details related to LSA protection.

Answer (score 0):

In order to load a custom DLL I needed to change local policies.

In Local Group Policy Editor, navigate to **Administrative Templates > System > Local Security Authority**.

Enable **Allow Custom SSPs and APs to be loaded into LSASS**.

Disable **Configure LSASS to run as a protected process**.

My DLL is NOT signed.

This allowed my DLL to load into LSASS.

This was on a Windows 11 system.